# Opening port 8080 on Windows firewall

Tags: windows, firewall, port, port-forwarding, windows-firewall

I am not sure if I am just missing a trick here and it will be something rather simple, or if I am trying to do something that just isn't going to work..

Anyway, I have an asp.net site and I am using IIS to host it. I have changed the bindings to port `8080` so IIS should be listening on this port.

When I have the bindings set to port `80`, I can connect from a remote computer (`ip:80`) no problem (I have a rule in Windows Firewall for port `80`).

So what I am doing now is, making IIS listen on port `8080` for this site, adding a rule in to Windows firewall for port 8080, and then forwarding port `8080` on my router, although it will not allow me to connect. When I check if this port is open, it tells me it is closed.

Will Windows Firewall not allow you to open individual ports, or do you have to add an application to the firewall?

I have looked all around the internet and everyone just adds the application as an exception to the firewall, I just want to allow a port to be opened and configure it in Windows Firewall.

Comment: Have you verified that the web site is listening on port 8080? You can do this with netstat fairly quickly.